# Press any Key to Continue..Android

Tags: android

I want to create an activity with message " Press any key to continue..." and by clicking any key on the keypad...another activity must be started.

Can any one give an idea how can I implement this?

Comment: So what should those of us do in your app who don't have a keypad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override activity method onKeyUp:

```
public boolean onKeyUp (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //here you can start your activity, i.e. this way:
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(YourActivity.this, YourAnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
    return true;
}
```

You don't have to pay attention on what keyCode was sent to your method, cause this does not matter.

Also you can override `onKeyDown()` instead of this. In this case, activity will start a little bit earlier (after you push you finger down).

Happy coding :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!I have to only choose one best answer...thanks for your answers ntc and Rasael.! :)

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

Intent i = new Intent(YourActvity.this, NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: You may want to return **after** starting the new Activity though :-)

Comment: I'm not awake enough to see if you're joking or not, so I'll bite... doesn't your `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` statement just, well, return? So that the rest won't be executed?

Comment: i'm was just joking.. and you got me.. and that's a serious issue.. i'll edit it.. chill buddy..

Answer (score 1):

In First Activity's
onCreate

```
TextView view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
view1.setText("Press any key to Continue..");
```

and override this method

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
final Intent i = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
    startActivity(i);               

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```